# Eloquent property inheritance / overwrites

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, orm, eloquent

We have an application (php-laravel-moloquent-mongodb), which serves multiple clients, whom must not interfere each other.

We are storing models for different clients in the same collection, discriminated by a `_client` field. Most of models are relates to only one client, but sometimes we want to have "global" models. In those cases the client should be able to overwrite some fields, without affecting the other client's models.

I'm thinking about the following solutions, but not sure which is the best one, or if there is any better one.

- Copying the model on update to a new model, if its `_client` is `all`.

  - Loosing any existing relations
  - Can't inherit the modifications to unmodifield fields
- Keeping modifications as a submodel

  - Can be a big storage / retrieve overhead

Is there a best practice, or anything that I did not considered? Is there any existing implementation for this functionality?

Comment: If your question has the word `best` in it, then it's not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy removed last question (that asked for the best answer), hope the rest is a good fit for stackverflow

Comment: `Is there a best practice, or anything that I did not considered? Is there any existing implementation for this functionality?` - We need to solve specific problems, not theoretical ones. can you give a more concrete example of the issue at hand? This may be a better fit for `codereview.stackexchange.com` or perhaps `reddit`?

Comment: specific problem: model inheritance. There is a model ( `{client:"all", property:"foo", guid:"all.a"}` ) which can be overwritten by client "cl". Then with option 1, it could become `{client:"all", property:"foo", guid:"all.a"}, {client:"cl", property:"bar", guid:"cl.b"}`, or with option 2 it could become `{client:"all", property:"foo", guid:"all.a", overwrites:{cl:{property:"bar"} }`.